# Cannot search corporate LDAP from docker container

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-security, ldap

I'm using Spring Boot LdapTemplate to get data from corporate LDAP. Everything is working fine when running code from development non-docker environment (Windows10 with IntelliJ).

When the application is deployed in docker container, then there is a problem when executing search line:

```
Filter f = new EqualsFilter(ldapAttributeEmail, email);
ldapTemplate.search(ldapBase, f.toString(), new MyAbstractCtxMapper());
```

docker image is openjdk:17-jdk-slim:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
EXPOSE 443
ARG JAR_FILE=app.war
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.war
ARG PROPS_FILE=application.properties
ADD ${PROPS_FILE} application.properties
ARG TIKA_CONFIG_FILE=tika-config.xml
ADD ${TIKA_CONFIG_FILE} tika-config.xml
ARG CERT_FILE=cert.p12
ADD ${CERT_FILE} cert.p12
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.war"]
```

Spring Boot version is 2.7.2 and dependency for LDAP is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

LDAP connection is configured in configuration class, credentials are ok:

```
@Configuration
public class LDAPConfiguration {

private final String ldapUrl;
private final String ldapUser;
private final String ldapPassword;

@Autowired
public LDAPConfiguration(
        @Value("${ldap.url}") String ldapUrl,
        @Value("${ldap.principal}") String ldapUser,
        @Value("${ldap.password}") String ldapPassword) {
    this.ldapUrl = ldapUrl;
    this.ldapUser = ldapUser;
    this.ldapPassword = ldapPassword;
}

@Bean
public LdapContextSource ldapContextSource() {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();

    contextSource.setUrl(ldapUrl);
    contextSource.setUserDn(ldapUser);
    contextSource.setPassword(ldapPassword);

    return contextSource;
}

@Bean
public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
    return new LdapTemplate(ldapContextSource());
}
```

}

thrown exception is:

```
org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: LDAP connection has been closed; remaining name 'ou=People,o=XXX'
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:228) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:401) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:332) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:574) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:534) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:550) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:566) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at com.nokia.mn.mdmt.security.LDAPSearchProvider.getDnForUser(LDAPSearchProvider.java:53) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.nokia.mn.mdmt.security.LDAPAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(LDAPAuthenticationProvider.java:60) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.nokia.mn.mdmt.security.LDAPAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(LDAPAuthenticationProvider.java:114) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:132) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar!/:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
  Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: LDAP connection has been closed
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapRequest.getReplyBer(LdapRequest.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.readReply(Connection.java:444) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getSearchReply(LdapClient.java:639) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.search(LdapClient.java:562) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.doSearch(LdapCtx.java:2014) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1873) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1798) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:358) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:341) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:296) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$4.executeSearch(LdapTemplate.java:326) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:367) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

What could be cause of above exception ?

Comment: ldap doesnt use port 443....

Comment: Sure, port 443 is to allow https connection to application from outside. And what we want is to connect to outside LDAP from inside application. Do I really also need to expose LDAP port to do this ?